# changing lower to uppercase without built in functions of string

Tags: javascript

I have created the loop to search the array for the string length and after that I am sort of stuck to where to go to next after that because y of the others.

```
function uppp(string) {
var c = '';
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Assignments aren't usually arbitrary; your instructor, tutorial, or course will have covered the necessary topics to make it possible for you to do this. **Review your course materials, class notes, etc.,** and try to do the work. *If* you run into a *specific* problem, research it thoroughly, [search thoroughly here](/help/searching), and if you're still stuck post your code and a description of the problem. People will be glad to help.

Comment: At best look into https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charCodeAt.

Comment: Why did you edit out .length? That is just wrong - also you return c but don't set it to anything

Comment: leng? and \ ? Please click the `<>` and create a [mcve] - you need to do c+= converted char and not change string[i]

Comment: ops made mistake look again

Comment: For which characters and locales? There are 1986 lowercase letters.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a homework question, so I'm only going to give you hints!

First, look into the concept of ASCII codes:
https://www.w3schools.com/charsets/ref_html_ascii.asp

You'll notice that the `character codes for a-z (lowercase) are 97-122`.
Likewise, the `character codes for A-Z (capitalized) are 65-90`.

---

#### High-level solution

Iterate through your string, checking if each character is lowercase.

> **Notes:** `'a'.charCodeAt(0) === 97` and `String.fromCharCode('a'.charCodeAt(0) + 1); === 'b'`

With these notes in mind, see if you can develop a solution.

Comment: would i have to implement if and else statments along side the ascii codes?

Comment: Depends how you implement your solution. Update your original question with your attempt and we'll go from there!

Comment: Try running your code, and check the error. One of the great things about programming is that you can run it a **million** times and it doesn't cost you anything but your time. Keep iterating through the program, running it, fixing errors, and trying new solutions until you get your solution. Try not to guess at each iteration, but instead think through the problem and see where you went wrong.

Comment: ok thanks for the help ill just do what you said and see if i can get it to work or not bye!

Comment: One last hint, you can change `string[i]` to `string.charCodeAt(i)` to get the ASCII character codes that I was talking about.

Comment: If my answer has helped solve your original issue, please mark it as the accepted answer. Currently there are roughly 4.5 million unanswered questions on SO, and it is important to allow contributors to focus on helping those who still need help.

Comment: [fromCharCode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCharCode) and [charCodeAt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charCodeAt) are functions of String prototype.

Comment: @Trent i have updated the new code am i doing it correct or no?

Comment: @AlanLarimer Good point, but I feel like those functions were not what the teacher was referring to.

Comment: @FrankJohnson Uh.. now you have basically no code in your answer?

Answer (score 0):

Look at the array functions such as [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), [join()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join), and [indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf).  How could two arrays, one of lowercase and one of uppercase letters, be combined with these methods to produce the desired outcome?

```js
var s = 'String is COOL!',
    result = '',
    lower = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z'],
    upper = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z'];

function makeUpper(x) {
  let index = lower.indexOf(x);
  return index > -1 ? upper[index] : x;
}

result = [].map.call(s, makeUpper).join('');

console.log(result);
```

Comment: not allowed to use in built functions so  icould not use those code you used

Comment: @FrankJohnson "without built in functions of string" (question title) or "not allowed to use in built functions" (comment)?  If the former, then my solution is allowed; if the latter, then the title needs to be corrected, Trent's answer is invalid, and technically there is no answer.

Comment: The comments on these two answers are another reason that I need to leave the SE network.